# How to create an unifying c# library project in "visual studio 2013" consisting of other library projects

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2013, namespaces, project

Maybe the solution is simple but i could not find it in the way i wanted to.

I have a main c# library project with all of my applications use via referencing that project.

Now i have created another small library project and i want all of my applications to see the namespace/classes inside of this new project as well.

Since i cannot/should not add reference of this new project to all of my projects. I want to extend my main library with this new small library .

However , just dragging classes inside the main library is not an option because i have more of these mini libraries which will need to be plugged in and out depending on situation.

*
Therefore i want to add a reference of this library to my main* library and make all of my applications see the new libraries code.
However , the idea is cool and i was expecting it to work, but it didn't work.

Am i missing something ? How else can i extend my main library ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Bob Horn in that this is not the way it is done (generally). However I have another possible solution. It's possible if the project is not yet too big, that is, its still practical to do it. I have found this can be done on all but the very largest of applications.

Essentially your problem was solved many moons ago by ancient programmers back in the stone age when they implemented the thing called "N-Tier" architecture. This should give you a hint that because your project is now growing, you need to restructure / refactor and rethink about it in a new/old way.

An example...Most projects need the following:

- Database layer (the classes that Entity frameworks, or nhibernate or whatever auto generates),
- Repository layer (traditionally called the Database Access Layer)
- Domain layer (also called the business logic layer among other not so nice names)
- Testing layer (for your unit / integration tests)
- Service layer (this lets all your back end stuff be self contained in one place)
- UI layers (this lets your various UI's access your system through the service layer)

Note the only layer with a plural is the UI layers. This is because you can write a console UI, a web UI, a UI for the Apple ICoffeeMaker, or IWashingMachine, or IBoobImplanter, or whatever new device Apple decides to invent next, a UI for windows, a UI for Linux, a UI for Android, and basically a UI for any device you want.

All these UI layers access the service layer, this forces all applications that want to access your system to do so in a way that is completely under the control of the service layer.

This also has the benefit of containing all your relevant code in a single place which has generally major benefits for maintenance, security, testability, validation etc and leaves the UI layers free to do what they do best...display the information.

Finally, you can also apply all the latest and greatest design patterns very easily to a system like this because all you have to do is implement interfaces between the layers you think it is necessary to decouple and you are well on the way to a full DI/IOC and all those other good things a healthy diet provides for your project.

Many people might say this is too much work for small projects but...

- You can template it to make it very quick and easy to do.
- If templated properly, you need only add the layers you really need as your system grows.

  - Although once you done this once, you will see the benefits and usually will start all new projects the same way (because it's just easier to start like this than to convert to it later as you will find out).
- You should take into account that any successful system always starts out small but inevitably

  - grows into a larger system,
  - Becomes part of much bigger systems,
  - Parts get reused by other systems.

and a proper structure from the start helps this growth.

I don't know if this answers your question but when I get spare time I will be making YouTube video tutorials explaining how to do this properly.

Comment: Thanks for the effort , it doesnt exactly answer my problem but what you are suggesting is the right way to do projects, which is what i am doing atm. I will be interested to watch your videos , whenever they are ready.

I have started adding new functionalities "which is within that layers definition"  as classes inside folders. Into my main project, that way, other referencing projects can immediately see new interfaces and classes etc.
However there are still issues , but interestingly , i just cant find some of my problem's solutions . And my next question is one of them..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're missing something. :) It doesn't work that way. Just because your main library references another library, doesn't make that other library available to your applications. Your other apps have to reference those other libraries.

> Since i cannot/should not add reference of this new project to all of
>   my projects.

Why? If your apps need to reference them, then reference them. That's how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! This is really an ackward situation , i have been doing it the way like you said , until now, and i expected to finally solve this problem once i had time. 

See , i have many xamarin ios applications which use main library A, and many windows applications which use main library B

Now , they use seperate libraries because the dll's inside windows dont work in ios most of the time.

But i still have many shared* class files inside both of the A and B libraries , and they are getting out of sync.

I wanted to create a C library and subproject this inside A and B...